# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Unity cause by coding

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, nullreferenceexception

```
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Count);
    ADisplay.AnsA = ans[ansNum];
    ans.RemoveAt(ansNum); 
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Count);
    ADisplay.AnsB = ans[ansNum];
    ans.RemoveAt(ansNum);
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Count);
    ADisplay.AnsC = ans[ansNum];
    ans.RemoveAt(ansNum);
    ansNum = Random.Range(0, ans.Count);
    ADisplay.AnsD = ans[ansNum];
    ans.RemoveAt(ansNum);
```

The debug log shown "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How to randomize data in list without repeat

Comment: So, *which* object reference is `null`?

Comment: "How to randomize data in list without repeat" - search for *shuffle*